# Adding items to commandbar fabricui

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

We are using controls from UI Fabric. There is issue with CommandBar. If we manually add and remove items visible on CommandBar, the bar changes its width.

```
<CommandBar 
    styles={styles}
    buttonAs={customButton}
    items={this.getItems()}
/>
```

When props are changed, components rerender and getItems() might return 4 or 2 elements. If components has 4 and changed for 2 items, it works fine. If components has 2 elements and changed for 4, CommandBar has [...] icon - if the 4 icons not fit.

Documentation doesn't help on that.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the ... overflow menu to ever appear?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, as it is by design. There are various render functions available for you to customize the final output, but I don't know if those will allow you to prevent overflows. You can control the final order of items that way, if that will help